# 100% height, nested table, in standards mode

Tags: html, quirks-mode

I am trying to fix a display issue we are having with some tables (nested).  In short, we show a page listing products.  Each product is displayed in it's own table.  And each of these is nested in a larger table to layout the page.  Unfortunately, some of the inner tables have slightly more content than others and they end up being different sizes, causing others not to fill the containing cell.

For example:

```
<table style="height:500px; background:blue;">
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top">
            <table style="background:red; height: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td>hello</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In quirks mode, the red table, fills the blue table, so you basically see a red table, with a blue border.

In standards mode however, the inner table does not expand to fill the blue table.  Causing the layout to be not at all as anticipated.

How can I fix this behavior?  I don't want to render in quirks, as that will end up creating a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: I'm curious; why are you nesting tables? If you're using them for layout, you shouldn't.

Comment: Since nobody else has said it, _tables are not for layout, please don't use them as such_. :)

Comment: @Nightfirecat, I realize that.  Unfortunately I didn't write this code, just trying to fix a display issue with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `style="height: 100%;"` on the `<td>` and `<tr>` tags.  Setting height to 100% needs every parent to have a defined height.

Comment: That seems to work for my sample...but in the actual page, this table is nested VERY deep, changing parents heights all along is impractical.  Is there another way?

Comment: Sorry, I know it's a pain, but I have never found any other way.  It's a known issue that you can find a lot of sites talking about.  The only other option is to set a px height on the inner table.

Comment: You only need to define heights between the table with 100% up to any parent that use px (or em or something not %).  You don't have to go all the way to the root unless it's % all the way up.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the height of the outer table, set the height of the `<td>` and `style="height: 100%;"` on the nested table.